# Java/Android - ECDH Encryption - Create ECPublicKey from String

Tags: java, android, encryption, ecdh

I have a little problem with the ECDH (Elliptic-curve Diffie-Hellman) encryption.
I use the BouncyCastle library.

Here is my function to generate keys :

```
public static KeyPair generateECKeys() {
    try {
        ECNamedCurveParameterSpec parameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolp256r1");
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(parameterSpec);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        return keyPair;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        Log.d("Error - ",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I encode my public key in base64 with :

```
String keyPairA_public_base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyPairA.getPublic().getEncoded());
```

Here is an example of the key received :

```
keyPairA_public_base64 = "MFowFAYHKoZIzj0CAQYJKyQDAwIIAQEHA0IABGuSxmgwVGLHwcVhSf7C4/BfxfL4pGixHht8rWjPMBMTH5Vav1RQnf/Ucv9rLpD3M6ad8hHotwP5IpFsQT3hRkg="
```

Now, I need to generate an ECPublicKey object with the public key (String).

```
ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("brainpoolp256r1");
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", new BouncyCastleProvider());
ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("brainpoolp256r1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
ECPoint point =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), keyPairA.getPublic().getEncoded()); // Error here : Invalid point encoding 0x30
ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(point, params);
ECPublicKey pk = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

But, I have an error : **Invalid point encoding 0x30** when I use *ECPointUtil.decodePoint()*

I don't understand how I can solve this error and if I use the right way to create an ECPublicKey object from a string.

Can you help me please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ECPointUtil.decodePoint()` expects a raw public key. `keyPairA_public_base64` on the other hand is a Base64 encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format (i.e. not a raw public key) and can be imported as follows:

```
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
...
X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpecA = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyPairA_public_base64));
KeyFactory keyFactoryA = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH");
ECPublicKey publicKeyA = (ECPublicKey)keyFactoryA.generatePublic(x509EncodedKeySpecA);
```